# What do "mod $2x$" and "mod $x$" mean when used with angles?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, proof-explanation, triangles, angle

> I do not understand what the notation "$\operatorname{mod}{2x}$" or "$\operatorname{mod}{x}$" means in a geometric proof involving angles.

I need to understand a proof of a lemma about the Illumination Problem in Euclidian Space; the proof's author is George Tokarsky (1991). See the images below. Can you help me understand?

[image]

[image]

Thank you, very much! ;)

Comment: $a\pmod x=a-\lfloor \frac ax\rfloor x$

Answer (score 1):

We are given that $x$ divides $90.$
Usually we only make such statements in the case where $x$ is an integer,
and presumably if we were to look at the larger context of the problem where it appears in the book, it would be clear that we are meant to interpret it so that $x$ is an integer.

We are also told about a triangle that has one angle measuring $x$ degrees
and one angle measuring $nx$ degrees.
Now observe carefully: $x$ degrees is not an angle, it is merely the *measure* of an angle; and $x$ without the word "degrees" attached to it is not the same thing as $x$ degrees.
By itself, $x$ is neither an angle nor even the measure of an angle;
$x$ is just a number, specifically, an integer.

So when you see something like $\theta \equiv 90 \mod 2x$
in the proof, it is a lot like when we write something like
$y \equiv 11 \mod 30.$
Of course there is only ever one integer named $30,$
whereas $2x$ could be any of several different possible integers,
but still $2x$ is a positive integer and can be used as a modulus.

---

That's what it *means.*
To tell whether all the statements that are made regarding the integer numbers of degrees in various angles are *true,* you have to consider the geometry of triangles and of pool shots.
But that seems to me to be the topic of a different question.

Comment: Very thanks. I have some questions:
 ** θ ≡ 90 mod 2x ** would be the quotient in the 90 / 2x division?
** 11 mod 30 ** is 8?
What happens when **tetta** is ** 0 mod x **? It would the quotient of ** 0 / x **? I'm confused since this division is indetermined...
And the last: How can I write ecuations in the write box?

Comment: $\theta\equiv90\mod2x$ means that the remainder of $\theta$ divided by $2x$ is the same as the remainder of $90$ divided by $2x$--if you do it by remainders, you have to do it on both sides of the $\equiv$ sign, and nobody cares what the _quotient_ is when working with a modulus. I don't understand your question about $\mod30$, and you are wrong about $0/x,$ because $0/x=0,$ a perfectly valid division when $x > 0.$

Comment: To format equations, you can start here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: "We measure all angles $mod 2x$" .May be can you help me to understand that?

Comment: "We measure all angles $\bmod 2x$" means that whenever you have an angle of $y$ degrees, you don't ask, "Is $y=15$?" Instead, you ask, "Is $y\equiv 15 \mod 2x$?"

Comment: And why $2x$ and no $x$ or whatever?

Comment: Probably because if you try just looking at everything $\bmod x$ and not $\bmod 2x,$ you can't prove the theorem. Why do we ever use one number rather than another? You asked what a notion means; I think I have said what it means. Merely knowing what the notation means does not make the proof trivial to understand, however. Perhaps there were other examples earlier that explained how "pool shots" work, or perhaps this is an advanced example for students who have seen that concept elsewhere.